# tooltip icon in a form

Tags: forms, tooltips

Where to add a tooltip's icon in a form's input field?

Let's assume we have a form with a simple input field like:

```
 label: <input>
```

and we want to place a tooltip icon "?". Does it matter where we place it, for example:

```
label ?:  <input>
```

vs

```
? label: <input>
```

vs

```
 label: <input> ?
```

What is the least annoying option for the user, but still clear and visible? Or are all approaches good?

Comment: I believe the first one first one is the most appropriate, I read the label, digest the info, if it's not clear I get more information BEFORE I write down my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would go with

label: textfied (?)

for a user who doesn't need the hint, it's safely tucked away AFTER the textbox so it won't distract him.

I am assuming the 'tip' here is to guide users who have no idea what to enter in a particular field as opposed to preempting a frequently entered wrong answer (eg: formatting...in which case the hint must always be displayed rather than a using tooltip).

Comment: accepted, thanks for pointing out the _purpose_ of the tooltip! you assume right that my intention was to just give a hint for users who have no idea what to type in, however the point about formatting is very nice!